# Add new column for unique (A, B) or shared (both) groups based on column values and grouped by an ID

Tags: r, group-by, compare, aggregate

My data table is in the following form:

```
id    source
1     A
1     B
2     A
3     B
4     A
4     B
```

I want to make a new column which is grouped by **`id`** and has the value reflective of the corresponding **`source`** value (ie. `A, B, or Both`) Where `both` would be used if the **`id`** corresponds to both `A` and `B`.

I want the output to be as such:

```
id    source    source_group
1     A         both
1     B         both
2     A         A
3     B         B
4     A         both
4     B         both
```

Bonus if you can make it general purpose to handle additional values for *`source`*, such as `A, B, C, D, ... etc.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for reference, here is an arguably more appropriate benchmark:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

DT = data.table(id=seq(1e5))[,
  .(source = c(if (runif(1) > .5) "A", if (runif(1) > .5)"B")), by=id]
DF = data.frame(DT)

microbenchmark(
dplyr = 
  DF %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(gr = if(n()>1) "both" else as.character(source)),
dplyr_dt = 
  DT %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(gr = if(n()>1) "both" else as.character(source)),
ave = DF$gr <- 
  ave(as.character(DF$source), DF$id, FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1) "both" else x),
dt  = DT[, gr := if (.N > 1) "both" else as.character(source), by=id],
dt2 = DT[, 
  gr := as.character(source)][ DT[, if (.N > 1) 1, by=id][, V1 := NULL], 
  gr := "both", on = "id"],
  times=10)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    dplyr 1200.13579 1215.56997 1328.73931 1245.81556 1252.66023 1828.02921    10
 dplyr_dt   38.43108   41.58004   47.98858   43.89661   49.27464   68.64005    10
      ave  149.67549  153.03421  167.09148  163.19261  181.60074  191.22481    10
       dt   32.31500   33.60741   41.00644   35.80188   37.60350   65.76292    10
      dt2   25.99567   26.44592   28.11141   28.19138   28.55474   31.42691    10
```

I have no idea why `ave` is doing worse here. Maybe it is as @bunk said, that `ave` doesn't scale well to many groups. Dplyr is slow on a data.frame, but faster when using a data.table backend (as advertised).

For what it's worth, my data.table solution is a bit different (justifying a separate answer?):

```
DT[,
  gr := as.character(source)
][DT[, if (.N > 1) 1, by=id][, V1 := NULL], 
  gr := "both"
, on = "id"]
```

First, it sets `gr` equal to to `source`, then it replaces it with `both` for those groups with two rows.

Comment: nvm what I said, more than half of `ave` runtime is spent in `interaction`

Comment: To anyone paying attention: sorry about that. I had a bug or two there. The results are not substantially changed except now we can see that dplyr is slow on a data.frame. As the dplyr folks say, if you need speed, you can use dplyr with a data.table "backend".

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ave()`

```
df$source_group <- with(df, {
  ave(as.character(source), id, FUN=function(x) if(length(x) > 1) "both" else x)
})
```

which gives

```
df
#   id source source_group
# 1  1      A         both
# 2  1      B         both
# 3  2      A            A
# 4  3      B            B
# 5  4      A         both
# 6  4      B         both
```

Or as David suggests, we can use *data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, source_group := if(.N > 1) "both" else as.character(source), by = id]
```

which gives

```
df
#    id source source_group
# 1:  1      A         both
# 2:  1      B         both
# 3:  2      A            A
# 4:  3      B            B
# 5:  4      A         both
# 6:  4      B         both
```

Note that both of these assume the `source` column to be of factor class.

Comment: I was more thinking comparing against the overall unique values in `df`, something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, source_group := if(setequal(unique(source), unique(df$source))) "both" else as.character(source), by = id]` as a more general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tab%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(gr = ifelse(length(source)==2, 'both', source))

  id source   gr
1  1      A both
2  1      B both
3  2      A    A
4  3      B    B
5  4      A both
6  4      B both
```

In fact Richard's ave approach, with this data, will be faster than dplyr/ifelse or dplyr/if-else and even datatable versions.

```
library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(
  Dplyr=tab%>%
    group_by(id)%>%
    mutate(gr = ifelse(length(source)==2, 'both', source)),
  Dplyr2=tab%>%
    group_by(id)%>%
    mutate(gr = if(length(source)==2) 'both' else source),
  Ave = tab$source_group <- with(tab, {
    source <- as.character(source)
    ave(source, id, FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1) "both" else x)
  }),
  DT=setDT(tab)[, source_group := if(setequal(unique(source)
                                              , unique(tab$source))) "both" else as.character(source)
                , by = id]
  , times=1000L)

>bench
Unit: microseconds
   expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  Dplyr 2576.491 2917.6415 4172.977 3213.224 4582.343 21174.76  1000
 Dplyr2 2568.691 2899.7835 3972.390 3191.671 4613.338 16547.67  1000
    Ave  668.344  792.3245 1134.236  854.109 1293.993 18753.86  1000
     DT 1083.801 1201.2130 1622.587 1285.577 1779.035 10232.48  1000
```

Comment: The speed difference could be due to `ifelse` vs Richard's `if`/`else`, though I do expect to see `ave` being faster, yeah.

Comment: Oh, by the way, you probably want to do such benchmarks on larger tables than a few lines. For `Dplyr2`, you can use `n()` in place of `length(source)`

Comment: dplyr will be faster for a 60000 lines dataframe.